# Android app changes home screen on suspend

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-launcher, homescreen, suspend

When I suspend my app by pressing the home button, the app immediately disappears revealing the home screen. The top-most icon on the home screen is drawn inside a white shaded box, as if the icon is somehow selected. This happens before onPause() is run but does not happen if finish() is run.

This only happens with my app. I've seen it on Android 6 and 7. What could I be doing to cause this?

More information: 
I can prevent this from happening if I activate a popup menu before pressing the home button.

Still more information:
Removing the 4th line makes the problem go away. This is a TextView.

`curTitle.setFocusable(true);
    curTitle.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    curTitle.requestFocus();
    //curTitle.requestFocusFromTouch();`

I still don't understand it.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWJCQ.png

Comment: Seems to be a feature of your launcher.  Remember that the launcher is an app and can have any behavior it wants.

Comment: Unlikely since it only happens with one program.

Comment: Since there's no API for an app to talk to the launcher, its pretty much impossible its the app.

Comment: Maybe something is leaking from the app to the launcher. Maybe the problem lies outside the app. I would still like to know why I am so lucky to encounter this. Thanks to all for your consideration.

Comment: this may be caused by instrumentation (I know this behavior, when using the default launcher in combination with a test app), hard to believe it would be caused by the app itself. except there might be some key-code leaking; just connect a hardware keyboard and hit the `<tab>` key to see what I mean.

Comment: this topmost icon might even be already selected, before minimizing the app ...the screenshot does not really help in providing an accurate answer, unless having seen the code which produces it; try to isolate the issue in a simple app package.